# Error "TS2339 Property 'elseblock' does not exist on type ''"

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

I'm trying to do an *If Else* with Angular:

```
<form [formGroup]="searchForm">
    <input formControlName="search"  placeholder="search show"/>
</form>
<div *ngIf="searchForm.value.search; else elseblock">
    search 
</div> 

<ng-template #elseblock>
   Listing
</ng-template>
```

But Typescript gives me an error:

> error TS2339: Property 'elseblock' does not exist on type ''.

How can I fix it?

Here my TS file :

```
 export class ShowListComponent implements OnInit{
      searchForm :any;
      showsList:any = [];
    
      constructor(
        private showsService: ShowsService,
        private router : Router,
        private formBuilder: FormBuilder
      ) {
        this.searchForm = this.formBuilder.group({
          search: '',
        });
      }
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.showsService.getShowsList()
          .subscribe(response => {
            this.showsList = response;
        })
      }
    
      goToShowDetail(show: any) {
        let title:string = show.name.replaceAll(' ','-').toLowerCase()
        this.router.navigate([this.router.url, show.id, title])
      }
    
      
    }
```

Comment: You should need a semicolon after the condition afaik: `*ngIf="searchForm.value.search; else elseblock"`

Comment: I tried but that doesn't change

Comment: Can you Share your ts file please?

Comment: I've add to the question

Comment: there should be a semicolon (`;`) before the 'else' keyword in the ng-if.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### This is the right syntax for the ngIf else block in angular:

```
<form [formGroup]="searchForm">
  <input formControlName="search"  placeholder="search show"/>
</form>
<div *ngIf="!searchForm.value.search; else elseblock">
  search
</div>

<ng-template #elseblock>
  Listing
</ng-template>
```

### What was wrong?

```
<form [formGroup]="searchForm">
  <input formControlName="search"  placeholder="search show"/>
</form>
<div *ngIf="searchForm.value.search else elseblock">. ====> You missed the semi colon here
    search 
<div> ====> You should use a closing tag instead (</div>)

<ng-template #elseblock>
   Listing
<ng-template>  ====> Also here, it should be a closing tag (</ng-template>)
```

Beside that, everything looks just fine.

Comment: I don't know which IDE do you use, but I think you should consider using a known one and installing the Angular Language Service extension  – VS Code for example

Comment: Hello  @PixD, I'm very sorry. I restart my project after a break and I verify your proposition and you were right , my <div> was not closed -_- Very stupid error ! 
THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!

Answer (score 0):

> 'elseblock' does not exist on type Angular

Usually Suggests that TypeScript is unable to find a property named 'elseblock' on the type it expects.

To use the else block with ngIf in Angular, you need to make sure that you are using the correct syntax. Here's an example of how you should use ngIf with else:

```
<div *ngIf="condition; else elseBlock">
  <!-- Content to be displayed when condition is true -->
</div>
<ng-template #elseBlock>
  <!-- Content to be displayed when condition is false -->
</ng-template>
```

Make sure that you have declared the elseBlock template reference variable correctly and that you are using the correct syntax in your Angular component template.

Here's how you would declare the condition in your component:

**In your component.ts:**

```
condition: boolean = true; OR condition: boolean = false;
```

**In your template.html :**

```
<div *ngIf="condition; else elseBlock">
  <!-- Content to be displayed when condition is true -->
  <p>This is displayed when condition is true.</p>
</div>
<ng-template #elseBlock>
  <!-- Content to be displayed when condition is false -->
  <p>This is displayed when condition is false.</p>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: I have just added the input for my form which allows you to do "searchForm.value.search".. I absolutely have to go through the TS file anyway?

Comment: Can you check the code provided by me with condition being true and false. if it renders properly that means its basically in form and in ts file

Comment: Same error from Typescript :(